# update and delete row in database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an database like this:

```
"id", "ingredients_id", "recipes_id", "qta", "created_at"
"1", "Acqua",         "Ricetta1", "100", "2014-04-05 10:34:13"
"2", "Alcolico Gin",  "Ricetta1", "200", "2014-04-05 10:34:13"
"3", "Amido di Mais", "Ricetta1", "300", "2014-04-05 10:34:13"
"4", "Acqua",         "Ricetta2", "330", "2014-04-05 10:34:15"
"5", "Alcolico Gin",  "Ricetta2", "440", "2014-04-05 10:34:15"
"6", "Amido di Mais", "Ricetta2", "550", "2014-04-05 10:34:15"
```

i have to update some value un the table, for examples only a quantity on the "Ricetta2".
Is better to delete all the row and recreate the new row with the new data or update only the value that are changed?
I think so because if the user have deleted an ingredient when I recreate the recipe "Ricetta2" i have only 2 ingredients.
is correct or there are a best method for Update/Delete the table?

I use this code for Updating:

```
public long Updatedb_Ingredienti_for_db_Recipe(StructRicetta rct) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    long Ingredienti_id = -1;
    int num = rct.get_num_Ingredienti();
    for (int i = 0; i< num;i++) {
        values.put(KEY_RECIPES_ID, rct.get_db_Ricetta_Name());  
        values.put(KEY_INGREDIENTS_ID, rct.itemsIngredients.get(i).getNome());
        values.put(KEY_QTA, rct.itemsIngredients.get(i).getQta());
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

        // updating row
        Ingredienti_id = dbWrite.update(TABLE_INGREDIENTS_RECIPES, values, KEY_RECIPES_ID + " = ", new String[] { String.valueOf(rct.get_db_Ricetta_Name()) });

        if(Ingredienti_id < 0)
            break;// errore scrittura
    }
    return Ingredienti_id;
}
```

But this code change all the row...

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating, to ContentValues you should pass only columns that you want to be updated. So, if you just want to update quantity (I guess it is a "qta" column), you should do only this:

```
 values.put(KEY_QTA, rct.itemsIngredients.get(i).getQta());
```

It is the job of dbWrite.update() method to know how to handle with ContentValues while updating. So:

```
 for (int i = 0; i< num;i++) {
        values.put(KEY_QTA, rct.itemsIngredients.get(i).getQta());
        // updating row
        Ingredienti_id = dbWrite.update(TABLE_INGREDIENTS_RECIPES, values, KEY_RECIPES_ID + " = ", new String[] { String.valueOf(rct.get_db_Ricetta_Name()) });
 }
```

If your where clause is ok, it should work.

Comment: ok,  the data came from a ListView, so if the user as deleted a row in the ListView how can Update the row that are missing?
it is better to delete the data and rewrite or not?

Comment: You cannot update the row that is missing. If user deletes (on ListView) some item, delete the row (syntax is the same as update). Then you should remove the item from ListView as well to prevent situations where user "updated" item that doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

For updating a particular data in a row, you have to use 'where' condition,
Example:

In your Main class

```
DBClass db = new DBClass(this);
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(DBHelper.COL_RECIPIES_ID, "Ricetta123");
String where = DBHelper.COL_ID + " = " + 4;
db.update_data(cv,DBClass.TableName,where);
```

(it will update the recipie_id column of that row where id =4)

In your Database class add this method

```
public int update_data(ContentValues cv, String TableName, String where) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    int rowid = (int) db.update(TableName, cv, where, null);
    return rowid;
}
```

Comment: ok,  the data came from a ListView, so if the user as deleted a row in the ListView how can Update the row that are missing?
it is better to delete the data and rewrite or not?